# Dell USC/LCC freezes, no iDRAC connection on PowerEdge R710

Tags: bios, dell-poweredge

The Unified Server Configurator keeps getting stuck on being halfway loaded.[image: frozen]

The dedicated iDRAC port doesn't seem to work at all (LED indicators show no signs of life).

Dell PowerEdge R710, BIOS version 1.2.6 updated to 6.6.0. LCC was showing up as firmware version 0.0.0.0, and 1.0.0.0 after the BIOS update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by swapping the CPUs back to E5500 series, downgraded the BIOS to 1.2.6, then went up in the following order:

- 2.0.13  - this is the one that added the microcode for E5600 series CPUs
- 2.1.15
- 2.2.10
- 3.0.0
- 6.0.4
- 6.0.7
- 6.4.0
- 6.6.0

I've read in multiple places that it's not recommended to make too big of a jump between versions, so even though it was a bit tedious, I went through them 1-by-1.

Since the system was brand new and nothing was configured yet, I quickly installed Windows on it, and used the packaged installers to install the iDRAC 2.90 Firmware.

After the fw update the iDRAC port came alive, I could actually connect to it, and USC also loaded properly!